# ERROR "MODULE NOT FOUND" on Typescript index.ts activation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js

i was building this discord bot using discord.js v13
and everytime i run my code (that i completly did not rip off from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMmUW4d3Noc&t=614s)

Here is my code: Package.json

```
  "name": "Ceeby",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0"
  }
}
```

Index.ts

```
  import DiscordJS, { Intents, Message } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Ceeby Is Active")
})

client.on('messageCreate', (Message) =>{
    if(Message.content === 'ping'){
        Message.reply({
            content: 'pong',
        })
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

.ENV file

```
TOKEN=<THIS IS MY TOKEN HERE>
```

i already tried doing it twice, restarting, reinstalling everything and still the same problem.
here is the error:
`Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js
- C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\index.ts
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\Users\Fady Mena\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\node_modules@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:679:30)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:22)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js',
  'C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js',
  'C:\Users\Fady Mena\Desktop\Ceeby\index.ts'
  ]
  }
  `

Comment: The contents of `index.ts` are the same as `package.json`, which is invalid.

Comment: @ArnavThorat Fixed

Answer (score 2):

Discord.js V13 requires a node version greater than 16.9.0 and you are running a version older than that as node:events was introduced in node V16+(Unsure which one exactly)
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js
[image]